# Is this instruction wrong? (movabs %al,0xe400000000004049)

Tags: c++, debugging, assembly

I am debugging some programs. In per-instruction debugging (Eclipse CDT), I have come across this:

```
movabs %al,0xe400000000004049
rex.WB
```

After executing the `movabs` instruction, debugging terminates with SEGV.
I have seen those instructions, out of which the second does not even look like one, heh.

Might be not caused by this, but I better ask.

That is GNU assembler syntax, as I work on Linux Gentoo 64bit, my CPU is `Intel 2600K`(i7 second gen).

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid instruction stream. Are you trying to execute data?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
0xe400000000004049
```

Migth be a little to big to put in al. on x86 (32bits) AL(8bits) is a part of EAX (32bits register)
So i assume (maybe wrong) that on 64bit arch AL is 16bits => 0xFFFF max.

Comment: AL is still 8 bits on x86_64. All the registers stay the same size, they're just subviews of the larger rax/rbx/rcx/rdx/rsi/rdi/rsp/rbp/rip registers.

Comment: `0xe400000000004049` is a memory address, not a value to be stored.

Comment: Ok learnt something. Always thougt the syntax was `movabs %al, [0xe400000000004049
]`, that why i thougt you put the 0xe400000000004049
 in AL

Comment: @grifos, don't forget that linux uses the god-awful AT&T syntax for assembler, so the destination is on the right.

Comment: @James me, being a Linux fanatic, must say that is not 'linux syntax', but obviously AT&T syntax. And it is not caused by the existance of Linux that GAS uses AT&T syntax. :)

Comment: I never said it was 'linux syntax'.  I pointed out that linux uses AT&T syntax.  :)

Answer (score 6):

The instruction

```
movabs %al,0xe400000000004049
```

is supposed to store the value of `al` in the address 0xe400000000004049. The latter address is not valid, because on current x86_64 architectures the upper 17 (seventeen) bit of addresses have to be either all zero or all one. 
Or expressed differently, the current virtual address space is 48 bit sign extended, that is from `0xffff 8000 0000 0000` to `0x0000 7fff ffff ffff`.

This may change in the future though - but we will most likely see some generations of cpus come and go.

Comment: I know that  the kernel is located at the very top, user applications at the very bottom, that is what you try to say. Now that is in the middle of all address space, i know. Thus: Nevermind

Comment: @imacake No, I try to say the the address you have given is illegal, no matter where the kernel or the applications are